# 'Rbenv command not found' when trying to run Gitlab CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, gitlab-ci-runner

When a job tries to execute it fails with the following:

> gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.4.2 (1e86428)
>   Using Shell executor...
>   stdin: is not a tty
>   Running on ci-runner...
>   Fetching changes...
>   Checking out f8858e83 as master...
>
> whoami
>   root
>   echo $PATH 
>   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
>   rbenv local 1.9.3-p551
>   builds/95c60cbb/0/xxx/xxxx.sh: line 27: rbenv: command not found
>
> Build failed with exit status 127

If I check $PATH as root on the ci-runner machine I have: `/root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/root/.rbenv/shims:/root/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

The multi-runner script is being run as a service and is started using `sudo gitlab-ci-multi-runner start`

The executor is 'shell', and rbenv was setup using instructions at https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

**Update** Added /root/.rbenv/bin to $PATH but now just get

> gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.4.2 (1e86428)
>   Using Shell executor...
>   stdin: is not a tty
>   Running on ci-runner...
>   Fetching changes...
>   Checking out f8858e83 as master...
>
> export PATH="/root/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
>   rbenv local 1.9.3-p551
>   rbenv: version `1.9.3-p551' not installed
>
> Build failed with exit status 1

Ruby 1.9.3-p551 is installed though.

Comment: What is the output of `rbenv install 1.9.3-p551 && rbenv global 1.9.3-p551 && ruby -v`?

Comment: @mudasobwa Returns "rbenv: no such command `install'"

Comment: I doubt you installed `rbenv` as specified in link you provided: this command is a part of an installation process.

Comment: If I log in to the machine and run that script it's fine. Definitely installed on the ci-runner machine.